# AddTextChangedListener to Loop-generated EditText views

Tags: java, android, for-loop, android-edittext, addtextchangedlistener

I'm new to Android development. I'm facing a dead end developing an app for a project. Please take some time and help me out.

**The problem:**
I am generating some `EditText` views nested in a `LinearLayout` using a `for loop`.

For example:

```
LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootview);
for (int i=0,j=10;i<j;i++) {
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    rootView.addView(et);
    et.setHint("EditText No. "+ i);
    et.setId(i);
} // This code is for example purposes only.
```

Now, I can't seem to understand how I can set an addTextChangedListener on the EditText that is focused at a particular time and set that text on other EditTexts. Please tell me what approach should I adopt to achieve this. I tried my best to explain the problem; however, if there is still any ambiguity, feel free to comment and ask. I'm waiting for a solution to this problem.

**In terms of screenshots:**

**What I have:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

I hope this clears things up!

**

### EDIT:

Thanks to TylerSebastian for the solution. I got it to work. Here is the final code: (Inside OnCreate() method)

```
final LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootview);
    for (int i=0,j=10;i<j;i++) {

        final EditText et = new EditText(this);
        rootView.addView(et);
        et.setHint("EditText No. "+ i);
        et.setId(i);
        final TextWatcher textwatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
                for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
                    EditText view = (EditText) findViewById(i);
                    if (view != et){
                        view.setText(s.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    et.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);
                } else {
                    et.removeTextChangedListener(textwatcher);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to a machine with AS on it atm so no guarantee that the following is bug-free, but this should point you in the right direction:

```
final LinearLayout rootLayout = ...;

// within your loop
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rootLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = rootLayout.getChildAt(i);

            if (view instanceof EditText && view != et) {
                ((EditText) view).setText(s.toString());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**edit**: so the above will cause an infinite loop - see my comment below

How about:

```
final LinearLayout rootLayout = ...;

// again, within your loop
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rootLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = rootLayout.getChildAt(i);

            if (view instanceof EditText && view != et) {
                ((EditText) view).setText(s.toString());
            }
        }
    }
};

et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
             ((EditText) view).addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        } else {
             ((EditText) view).removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        }
    }
});
```

basically, only the focused element will have the `textwatcher`

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for responding so quickly. When I use your solution, the app launches just fine but as soon as I type a number in any EditText, the app stops responding and logcat starts to get filled with lines like these for indefinite period of time.
`Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17184(564KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 5.756ms total 22.762ms`

Comment: haha yeah now that I think about it changing the text in one field with cause the text in another field to change, which will trigger its TextWatcher, etc. Give me a bit to think about it.

Comment: Works like a charm with a bit of modification. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

first add a LinearLayout in your XML like that

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
```

then create a new class

```
public class EditTextCust extends RelativeLayout  {

EditText status;

public EditTextCust(Context context, Model post, int inputType,TextWatcher textWatcher) {
    super(context);
    inflate(context, R.layout.edit_text_cust, this);
    status = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    status.setInputType(inputType);
    post.setData(status.getText().toString());
    status.setHint(post.getHint());
    status.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
}

public String getText() {


    return status.getText().toString();
}

public EditTextCust(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public EditTextCust(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
}
```

and creat new XML file names edit_text_cust for this custom view class

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/dateEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />
```

and creat model class to set your data

```
public class Model {

String hint;
String id;
String data;

public String getHint() {
    return hint;
}

public void setHint(String hint) {
    this.hint = hint;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

and in your class inside the for loop but this code

```
 Model model = new Model();
            model.setHint("HINT");
            model.setId("1");

            editTextCust = new EditTextCust(this, editTextCustModel, InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER, new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // getText from here use
                       s.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
            linearLayout.addView(editTextCust);
```

it's work with me correctly, and if you didn't understand any thing from this code just add comment and i will help you :)

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for this solution. I will get back after trying it out.

Comment: I don't think this does what OP wants... and is like *far far far* more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @TylerSebastian think you for your advice.

Comment: While this method might work, but @TylerSebastian 's solution was much more concise and to the point. Whatsoever, thanks a lot for taking your time to help me. That means alot!